# Cast expression failure on Generic

Tags: c#, generics

Apologize in advance, for such trivial question but I am confused

I have a class hierarchy as follows

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    public class ClassA {}
    public class TypeA<A> where A : ClassA
    {
        public A p1 { get; set; }
    }
    public class SubTypeA<A> : TypeA<A> where A : ClassA
    {
        public TypeA<A> p2 { get; set; }

        public void foo()
        {
            var x = new TypeA<ClassA>();
            var y = (TypeA<ClassA>) p2;
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Why can't C# cast `p2` to `TypeA<ClassA>` while `p2` is an instance of `TypeA<A>` where `A` is of type `ClassA`?

Thanks

Comment: Please remove the image and post the actual code so that we can copy the code to test.

Comment: There is no failure. Just because `A` inherits from `ClassA` it **does not mean** that `TypeA<A>` inherits from `TypeA<ClassA>` - it **does not**. They are two different types.

Comment: @Carsten - Which you can't do because only interfaces can be covariant in C#.

Comment: @Carsten - But you can't do as you suggest and define `Type<A>` as covariant.

Comment: @Carsten - I understand about making an interface covariant, but you suggested making the type covariant. The #facepalm remark is just rude.

Comment: @Enigmativity ... I ain't gonna argue here when there is an answer there - and if you find the #facepalm rude (which only was about your nitpicking on a quick comment) then that's your problem

Comment: @Carsten - Please stop being rude. I know you're a smart guy with good rep here. You generally give very good answers and comments, but in this case I think you made a small mistake which I was politely trying to point out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for [*covariance*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee207183.aspx) and this isn't supported on classes, but in interfaces and delegates.

Design an interface as follows:

```
public interface ITypeA<out A>
    where A : ClassA
{
    A p1
    {
        get;
    }
}

public class ClassA
{
}

public class TypeA<A> : ITypeA<A> where A : ClassA
{
    public A p1
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

public class SubTypeA<A> : TypeA<A> where A : ClassA
{
    public TypeA<A> p2
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public void foo()
    {
        var x = new TypeA<ClassA>();
        ITypeA<ClassA> y = p2;
    }
}
```

The drawback here is that a property of a covariant generic type isn't valid if it can be set.

### Type inference madness

I want to suggest you that you shouldn't use type inference over explicit typing everywhere.

See the following sentence in your question:

```
var y = (TypeA<ClassA>)p2;
```

If you could be able to do the whole cast (as you could test yourself isn't possible without covariance), you're using an explicit cast to provide the type of your variable, while the same can be better expressed as follows:

```
// Implicit cast
TypeA<ClassA> y = p2;
```

Implicit typing/type inference isn't always more readable and shouldn't be used to specify the type, because C# can explicitly define the type for a given reference declaration...

That's the reason behind my answer doesn't use an explicit cast:

```
ITypeA<ClassA> y = p2;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, let me to digest it!

Comment: @anonim No problem, you're welcome. Check this link to learn more about the topic ;) https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee207183.aspx Happy meal!!!

Comment: @anonim At the end of the day, it's the same as `IEnumerable<object> enum = new List<string>();` :D